# Orthogonalization of right/left eigenvectors of non-hermitian, matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a non-hermitian matrix, that had a complex diagonal, but is otherwise symmetric (not hermitian), there are different eigenvectors for the left and right associated with the same (approximate) eigenvalue.

Unfortunately, purely left eigenvectors aren't guaranteed to be orthogonal with respect to each other.  My question is twofold:  I believe they are guaranteed to be orthogonal with respect to the opposite eigenvectors:

so:
$$A R = \Lambda_L R$$
$$A^{H} L = \Lambda_R L$$
$$L^{H} R = I$$

Where $L$ and $R$ are the sets of left and right eigenvectors, respectively. Is this correct?  Where can I find more information on non-symmetric eigenvector problems.  And does anyone know any algorithms for orthogonalizing the $L$ and $R$ eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix $A$ is non-Hermitian, so the left eigenvectors are not guaranteed to be orthogonal to each other, and the same holds for the right eigenvectors. You can assume you have $A R = R \Lambda$ and $L^HA=\Lambda L^H$; there is only one diagonal $\Lambda$ matrix of eigenvalues.
From [here](http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~neufeld/numerical/lecturenotes10.pdf), you can left multiply the first by $L^H$ and right multiply the second by $R$ and equate to get
$$L^HA R = L^H R \Lambda = \Lambda L^HR$$
Since the diagonal $\Lambda$ commutes with $L^HR$, then $L^HR$ is diagonal(*). You can then scale the eigenvectors such that $L^HR = I$, so that $A = R\Lambda R^{-1}$.

(*) The caveat is that a diagonal matrix can commute with certain non-diagonal matrices as well. Suppose $\Lambda$ is organized so all the identical eigenvalues are placed consecutively. Then $L^HR$ must be at least block diagonal with diagonal blocks corresponding to the repeated (degenerate) eigenvalues. In this case, the eigenvectors corresponding to each degenerate eigenvalue can be orthogonalized and still remain eigenvectors, thus the original statement holds true.

For example, suppose a sub-block of left and right eigenvectors satisfy $Y^HX = M$, where columns of $X$ are right eigenvectors of a degenerate eigenvalue and $Y$ are the corresponding left eigenvectors, and $M$ is a small square matrix. If you compute the $LU$ factorization of $M=LU$, then $X' = XU^{-1}$ and $Y' = YL^{-H}$ are blocks of orthogonalized eigenvectors.

Comment: So, $L^H R$ is, assuming non-degenerate eigenvalues, diagonal.  I know I can use Gram-Schmidth to enforce $L^H R = 1$ (assuming we want normalized eigenvectors).  Is there a way to modify the Householder orthogonalization routine to work on this weird, non-mutual orthogonalization?

Comment: I was incorrect in saying Gram-Schmidt. I have described an example process for doing this.